# Schengen visa through Swiss consulate in San Francisco

Tags: visas, schengen

I applied for and was granted a Schengen visa through the Italian embassy in May 2015. I wish to apply for a Schengen visa again through the Swiss consulate in San Francisco. Since my biometrics are already complete, I have mailed the documents to the consulate. Is there a way to track the visa process? How will they send the visa application reference number?  How long does it take to get an update?

Have any of you received a visa by mailing the Swiss consulate in San Francisco?  What was your experience?

Answer (score 3):

While [application is online](http://www.swiss-visa.ch/register/i210_select_country_view.action), the process creates a document (pdf) which you print and, separately, mail to the Consulate; online tracking is not included. As part of the print function, the information is sent online directly to the Consulate.

> [Visa processing](https://www.eda.admin.ch/countries/usa/en/home/visa/entry-ch/up-90-days/where-to-apply-schengen/atlanta.html)
>
> In general, the processing takes about 2 weeks once the application is complete. This does not include the time for mailing. However, in some particular cases, the processing time might be longer, especially if the central authorities have to be consulted.
>
> There is no need for you to contact the Consulate General about the status of your application. This office will contact you if further action on your part is required. Please also do not inquire about the arrival of documents you might have sent - if you do send an email, you will receive an automatic reply confirming the receipt; if you have sent a letter, please track it with your tracking number [via secure carrier: Fedex preferred, UPS and USPS ok].
>
> [Questions](https://www.eda.admin.ch/countries/usa/en/home/visa/entry-ch/work-permits/where-to-apply-work-permits/san-francisco.html)
>
> General visa questions are not answered. Only if you have a specific question that is not answered on our website, may your write an email to sfr.visa@eda.admin.ch or call the visa desk Monday through Friday between 1pm and 2pm only at 415-788-2272.